# Solspace user search with dynamic orderby

Tags: solspace, solspace-user, orderby, parameters

I'm trying to order my results from a [Solspace user search](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/user), but I can't find any way of sending a field to sort on via the same form as the main search one. The search results page redirects to a unique URL without passing any of the original form params (via get/post).

I can think of ways to do it via [Resource Router](https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router), or query string or cookie stuff, but none feel like the 'EE' way to do that.

i.e. how to get {something_to_order_by} from the top tag to the bottom?

```
{exp:user:search return="reports/members/results"}
  <input type="search" name="keywords" id="keywords" value="{keywords}" />
  <input type="text" name="custom_fields" id="custom_fields" value="{custom_fields}" />
  <input type="text" name="something_to_order_by" />
{/exp:user:search}

{exp:user:results orderby="{something_to_order_by}"}
  <table>
    <th><a href="/reports/members/results/{segment_4}/order:something_to_order_by">custom_field</a></th>
  </table>
{exp:user:results}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use orderby:

```
orderby="username"
```

No need for curly braces around the field name.

Check your stack trace and see if the orderby is being included in the query.

Comment: Thanks Jim, yes that works in the results tag, but how would I pass that as a dynamic parameter from the search form? Any extra inputs I add inside the search form, don't seem to be passed through to the results page.

Comment: I can see this would work for the standard users tag if I POSTed back a form [with dynamic parameters](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/legacy/user_3/users/#dynamic_parameters), but I'd like to combine that with the User:Search keywords into one form. It seems like the search/results tag doesn't work with POSTed data.